# A category with finite products or finite limits

Tags: category-theory

I am familiar with the notion of products and limits in category theory, but somehow struggling to understand the term "a category with finite products" or "with finite limits".

Does it mean that there are a finite number of products or limits in a given category?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A given category "has finite products" if for every finite set of objects a product exists in the category. So it definitely does not mean that the number of products in the category is finite.

Comment: @drhab Thank you for your reply. I thought the notion of product is defined between two objects. So does it mean given a finite set of objects, there exists a product between any two objects in that set?

Comment: No. The notion is not defined only for two objects. It is defined for sets/collections of objects. If e.g. $A_1,\dots,A_n$ are objects then object $P$ equiped with morphisms $p_i:P\to A_i$ serves as product of the $A_i$ if for every object $B$ and every tuple $(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ of morphisms with $f_i:B\to A_i$ there is a unique $f:B\to P$ such that $p_i\circ f=f_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. The category has finite products if for any finite set of objects such a product exist. This also for the empty set.

Comment: @drhab Thank you so much for your clarification. If you find the time, kindly rewrite what you wrote as an answer so that I could select it.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A_1,\dots, A_n$ (not necessarily distinct, and $n=0$ is allowed) are objects in a category $\mathcal C$ then an object $P$ equipped with morphisms $p_i:P\to A_i$ serves as product of the $A_i$ if for every object $B$ and every tuple $(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ of morphisms with $f_i:B\to A_i$ there is a unique morphims $f:B\to P$ such that $f_i=p_i\circ f$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

A category $\mathcal C$ **has finite products** if for every finite family of objects a product exists.

---

Special cases.

In special case $n=0$ we need an object $P$ such that for every object $B$ exactly one arrow $B\to P$ exists. This in order to guarantee the mentioned uniqueness. This means that $P$ must be a terminal object and the other conditions are then vacuously satisfied. So any category that has finite products will have a terminal element.

In special case $n=1$ a product of $A_1$ equipped with identity serves as product of $A_1$.

---

It is evident that in case $n=1$ a product exists. Further it can be proved that the existence of binary products (case $n=2$) implies the existence of $n$-ary products for $n\geq2$.

This together makes clear that for having finite products it is sufficient if the following conditions are satisfied:

- The category has a terminal object.
- The category has binary products.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your wisdom.